# Issue with Connecting to VNC Console Using VNC Viewer: Timeout Error

Tags: vmware, vnc, pyvmomi, vnc-viewer

I am facing an issue with connecting to a VNC Console using the VNC Viewer and would appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

```
   try:
    ticket = vm.AcquireMksTicket()
    print("VNC connection information for {}:".format(vm_name))
    print("Host: {}".format(ticket.host))
    print("Port: {}".format(ticket.port))
    print("Ticket: {}".format(ticket.ticket))
    print("SSL thumbprint: {}".format(ticket.sslThumbprint))
  except vmodl.MethodFault as e:
      print("Failed to get vnc connection information: {}".format(e.msg))
      exit(1)
```

**Output Received:**
I received the following details (note: sensitive data has been replaced with placeholders):

```
VNC connection information for VM_NAME:
Host: HOST_ADDRESS
Port: PORT_NUMBER
Ticket: TICKET_ID
SSL thumbprint: SSL_THUMBPRINT
```

**Issue Encountered:**
When I input these details into the VNC Viewer to connect to the VM, I encounter a timeout error with the message: "Timed out waiting for a response from the computer."

**Attempts to Resolve:**
Verified that the VM is running and accessible.

I am not sure what might be causing this timeout issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any suggestions on what could be going wrong or how to fix it?

[image: VNC Viewer Output]

Also I am currently using pyVim and pyVmomi as python package.

Thank you in advance for your help!